# bitmap in android post to a flask webserver using httpurlconnection

Tags: java, android, flask, httpurlconnection

I'm just trying to upload a bitmap to a server from inside android.

I googled some stuff and came up with this, it's practically the exact same as another post but it doesn't work. I'm not sure what's going wrong. From my debugging what's happening is when I do dos.flush() I get a "java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)" I don't understand why.

Here's my android code

```
class upload extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
        String attachmentName = "bitmap";
        String attachmentFileName = "bitmap.bmp";
        String crlf = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary =  "*****";

        try {
            HttpURLConnection huc = null;
            URL url = new URL("http://dontenvy.me:5000/");
            huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


            huc.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
            huc.setDoOutput(true);

            huc.setRequestMethod("POST");
            huc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            huc.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(huc.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + crlf);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + attachmentName + "\"; filename=\"" + attachmentFileName + "\"" + crlf);
            dos.writeBytes(crlf);

            Bitmap small = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(params[0], 100, 100, false);

            byte[] pixels = new byte[small.getWidth() * small.getHeight()];
            for (int i = 0; i < small.getWidth(); ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < small.getHeight(); ++j) {
                    //we're interested only in the MSB of the first byte,
                    //since the other 3 bytes are identical for B&W images
                    pixels[i + j] = (byte) ((small.getPixel(i, j) & 0x80) >> 7);
                }
            }

            dos.write(pixels);

            dos.writeBytes(crlf);

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + crlf);

            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
            huc.disconnect();

        }catch(MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null //once i get this working I'll do a response code return
    }


}
```

and here's my server side code. I'm just using flask because I figured it'd be easiest

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = "/home/luisfmh/vigeo/uploads"
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(["png", "jpg", "bmp"])

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit(".", 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upload_file():

    print len(request.files)

    if request.method == "POST":
        file = request.files["bitmap"]
        if file: ##and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"], filename))
            return '''success!!'''
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title> Upload new File</title>
    <h1> Upload new file</h1>
    <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
        <p><input type=file name=file>
            <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host = "0.0.0.0" )
```